# Verifying the purchase (receipt) of another application (Mac App Store)

Tags: swift, macos, mac-app-store, receipt-validation

TL;DR: Is there a way to verify that a user has purchased another app (of mine) from the Mac App Store?

---

In a brief, I want to completely rebrand one of my applications on the Mac App Store. The current version is very buggy and has a user base of nearly 90% pirates. I want to shut down the old application and completely rebrand it as a new product.

However, I don't want to completely screw over my current, legitimate customer base. I am hoping there is a solution to this. The way I was hoping to go about this was to:

- Create a new application – completely rebranded
- Make it free
- Have an In-App Purchase that unlocks the Pro version
- Allow customers of my previous app to *"restore their purchase"* to unlock the Pro version

The new app will have extensive anti-piracy measures. Furthermore, the current application requires a connection to one of my servers. When I release the rebranded app, I will shut down the current app.

I realize the forcing users to migrate may cause some backlash; however, I am hoping that, by providing the new and improved version 100% free, the backlash will pass.

Answer (score 2):

- Look for the old app using NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier
- get the receipt of this bundle using appStoreReceiptURL
- validate the receipt
- unlock functionality

Bare in mind that the terms and conditions of Apple say something along the line of "only appstore IAP should be used to unlock features; don't roll your own license mechanism"

Comment: `Bare in mind that the terms and conditions of Apple say something along the line of "only appstore IAP should be used to unlock features; don't roll your own license mechanism"` This is a good point. Perhaps I'll go with the new yearly model that seems to be so popular with all these new apps. Perhaps I'll release a "2019 Edition" in the fall, and just go with a cheaper app-price model.